# How to get all remaining month of year + next 4 years

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to  write a t-sql function, which returns a table of dates (representing month), starting with the next month and continue until the last month in 4 years.
e.g.:
1.7.2019
1.8.2019
...
1.12.2023

Maybe i am searching for the wrong keywords, but I can't find a suitable solution.

Comment: I suggest looking up a tally table.

Comment: You need a [calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)

Comment: Well, have you tried anything so far? A calendar table seems like an obvious choice for this kind of task.

Comment: A calendar table actually IS my current solution which was what I thought to be a quick and dirty solution to get the Problem solved. Now I was trying to improve this and also remove a "not needed" table. So you think I should keep the table which only contain the month of the next years?

Comment: A calendar table is not a dirty solution to this at all. It is in fact a very reasonable way to solve this. If you expand your calendar table to some more columns you have a great way of adding details to dates sporadically throughout the year. Very useful in a number of situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward using a tally table. I keep one as a view on my system. This generates 10,000 nasty fast. You can read more about tally tables from Jeff Moden [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1).

```
create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
GO
```

Now we can leverage this tally table to generate the data you need. We just need to use a little bit of date math to isolate the months you want.

```
select dateadd(month, t.N - 1, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()) + 1, 0))
from cteTally t
where t.N <= datediff(month
                , dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()) + 1, 0) --beginning of next month
                , dateadd(year, datediff(year, 0, getdate()) + 1, 0) --beginning of next year
                ) + 48 --add 48 because the next four years of months are static
```

Comment: I knew the about the cte. `; with <cte name> <(columns)> as (
 <select query> 
) select * from <cte name>`. but your cte is little different. I mean `E1, E2, E3`. can you tell about this.?

Comment: It is simply using multiple ctes where the later ones are referencing the first one to create a cartesian product so there are lots of rows. :)

Comment: So, can I summarize a calendar table is preferable to a tally table, but if this is not possible this solution should be used? (which I will mark as answer once I tested it)

Comment: I don't know that I would make that as a blanket statement either way. A tally table is incredibly powerful and flexible. It has been referred to as the "Swiss Army knife of t-sql". Either one is a perfectly valid solution to your problem. Which one is preferred depends partly on your system and partly on your preference.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a table or just need the data values? If you only need the data you only need this:

```
WITH mnths as (
  select dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()) + 1, 0) as mnth UNION ALL -- start date begining of next month
  select DATEADD(month,1,mnth) FROM mnths WHERE mnth< dateadd(month, -1, dateadd(year, datediff(year, 0, getdate()) + 5, 0)) -- end date - add 5 years to current year start and remove 1 month
)
select * FROM mnths
```

Not that if you change the date values and the results ended up retrieving more than 100 rows you need to add an extra line and set option MAXRECURSION to a higher value (e.g. 1000)

```
WITH mnths as (
  select dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()) + 1, 0) as mnth UNION ALL -- start date begining of next month
  select DATEADD(month,1,mnth) FROM mnths WHERE mnth< dateadd(month, -1, dateadd(year, datediff(year, 0, getdate()) + 5, 0)) -- end date - add 5 years to current year start and remove 1 month
)
select * FROM mnths
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)
```

Comment: Wow, this is an incredible short solution and works perfect. But I don't unterstand why the second select produces more then one line. I would have expected two lines with current and next month only.

Comment: And is it possible to mark two answers as solution to the question? Because I did ask for a table...

Comment: No @Krahmi. You can change (if you want), but you can only select one answer (the one you consider the best solution to your problem). One thing you can though, is vote up on this answer.